# Converting Time series data in FFT using client JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a web application that is getting time series data from some server using API's. What I want is to convert that time series data into the Fourier domain and display graphs based on that. 
I have tried libraries like P5.FFT but that seems to be not working in my case. What are some good libraries in client JS for Fourier Transform? I know there are modules in NodeJS but I can't use them as Node is for the server environment and I am doing it on the client side.

Comment: Q: What exactly were the problems you encountered with P5.FFT?  Q: Would this library work for you: https://github.com/turbomaze/JS-Fourier-Image-Analysis?

Comment: @paulsm4 P5.FFT is built for mostly to process sound data I guess. I am using fft.analyze([val1, val2, val3....]) but it's returning bunch of arrays with 0 on every index.

Comment: Regarding your concern with Node modules: [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Comment: @paulsm4 the link that you provide is using Images, In my case i have an array with values and corresponding timestamps, I am looking for a library that could input my array and convert into Fourier domain, just like Python has Scipy.FFTPack or NumPy.fft

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have tried browserify. But got some erros. Can you refer some good demo of browserify that i can use to implement my solution.